# Normal to surface spanned by 2 vectors

Tags: graphics, vector

I am trying to get the normal to a surface spanned by 2 vectors, but am getting an incorrect result.

```
cvec = {0.495984, 0.859069, 0.492034}
tvec1 = {0.98454, 0.783226, 0.131972}
rotatedPt = {0.957576, 0.82138, 0.0925392}
normal = Cross[tvec1 - cvec, rotatedPt - cvec];
normal = normal /Norm[normal];

Graphics3D[{
  {Red, Point[cvec], Point[tvec1], Point[rotatedPt]},
  {Blue, Arrow[{cvec, rotatedPt}], Arrow[{cvec, tvec1}]},
  {Green, Arrow[{tvec1, normal}]
  }]
```

[image]

As you can see, the green arrow is clearly not normal to the surface spanned by the blue arrows. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

---

Both answers below are perfectly correct. But I picked the one that addressed my question directly. Thank you both!

Comment: What is `normalCone`?

Comment: Sorry, should be `normal`. I made the correction

Comment: You can use `Normalize[Cross[...]]` , you don't need to divide by `Norm` on the next line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
    Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[0.015], Point[cvec], Point[tvec1], , 
  Point[rotatedPt], Black, Point[cvec + normal], Blue, 
  Arrow[{cvec, rotatedPt}], Arrow[{cvec, tvec1}],
  Green, Arrow[{cvec, cvec + normal}]
  }]
```

[image]

Have fun!

Answer (score 4):

We can get the normal to the polygon formed by the three points in several ways:

**1.** Use the function `` Region`Mesh`MeshCellNormals ``:

```
Region`Mesh`MeshCellNormals[ConvexHullMesh@{cvec, tvec1, rotatedPt},  2]
```

> ```
> {{0.447932, 0.77582, 0.444366}}
> ```

**2.** Use `ConvexHullMesh` with the option `PlotTheme -> "FaceNormals"`:

```
chm = ConvexHullMesh[{cvec, tvec1, rotatedPt}, PlotTheme -> "FaceNormals"]
```

[image]

and extract and process the normal line from `chm` to get the normal vector:

```
Normalize @ First @ Cases[Normal @ Show @ chm, Line[{a_, b_}] :> b - a, All]
```

> ```
> {0.447932, 0.77582, 0.444366}
> ```

**3.** Use `ListPlot3D` and extract `VertexNormals`:

```
First @ Cases[
  ListPlot3D[{cvec, tvec1, rotatedPt}, Mesh -> None], 
  HoldPattern[VertexNormals -> vn_] :> First[vn],
  All]
```

> ```
> {0.447932, 0.77582, 0.444366}
> ```

Comment: But how do I extract the actual value of the normal from this?

Comment: @ap21, please see the update.